Remote origin issue when using Github and AWS Codepipeline Integration for on-premise instances
I am using AWS Codepipeline to deploy/update a repository to an on-premise instance, the source of the repository is sourced from Github. When deploying the repository through codedeploy the origin of the remote repository is changed to the AWS codestar connection instead of keeping the original github remote origin.
Is there any way to keep the Github repo as the remote origin instead of AWS? The purposeis if I wish to manually pull an update directly from the remote repository on Github instead of using codedeploy.
I was able to manually change the remote origin and pull from github, but do not wish to do this every time for each instance.
